# How can I solve the limit by mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I use the `Limit` and `DiscreteLimit` to solve it but failed. How to solve it by Mathematica?
$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}n \left(\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{4}} \tan ^n\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) \, dx\right)^{1/n}$$

Comment: If you try `Integrate[Tan[x/n]^n, {x, 0, Pi/4}]` MMA evaluates a ConditionalExpression which constrains `0<n<1/2`. Might be the limit doesn't exist?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I'm quite sure, it does exist. At `n->Infinity` we can probably replace `Tan[x/n]` with `x/n`, then the limit is solvable and gives `Pi/4`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP The limit would be `1/4 \[Pi]^((4 + \[Pi])/\[Pi]) (4 + \[Pi])^(-4/\[Pi])` (not Pi/4). I only tried to indicate, that MMA can't integrate if `n>1/2`

Comment: @Ulrich `Integrate[Tan[x/n]^n, {x, 0, Pi/4}, Assumptions -> n > 1]` also gives an answer in terms of `Hypergeometric2F1`.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Yes ! But if we don't replace Tan[x/n] with x/n, what can we do to solve it by mathematica? Thank you.

Comment: @King.Max as you found, *as it is* Mathematica doesn't solve the limit. It needs some help (i.e. manual interference from the user). If my suggestion isn't acceptable to you, what kind of help would be acceptable? *Maybe* one could pass some options to `Limit` or to `Integrate`, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Try: `Limit[n*Integrate[Tan[x/n]^n, {x, 0, Pi/4}, 
     Assumptions -> n > 1]^(1/n) // PowerExpand, n -> Infinity]`

Answer (score 6):

`Integrate` returns an anti-derivative which seems reasonable for large `n`:

```
antiDeri = Integrate[Tan[x/n]^n, x];
Plot[antiDeri /. n -> 18, {x, 0, π/4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

And then

```
Limit[n Power[(antiDeri /. x -> π/4) - (antiDeri /. x -> 0), 1/n], n -> ∞]
```

> ```
> π/4
> ```

Comment: how simple a tricky solution can be...